# Protégé : OWL Reasoning and rdfs:subClassOf

Tags: owl, reasoning

I have got a problem about "reasoning mecanics". I created an ontology and i would like to understand some reasoning details :

[Here is a part of my ontology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmmb7.png)

As we can see, SubConcepts are link to SuperConcepts by rdfs:subClassOf axiom,
A concept can be "qualified_by" (objectProperty) a ListCommonName,
"Qualified_by" relation is transitive (and of course rdfs:subClassOf too).

First of all, I assert a "qualified_by" property on a root concept to his ListCommonName (which can be a sub-concept),

What I would like is :

by asserting a :

> concept1 "qualified_by" ListCommonName1

is there any possibility to infer :

> sub-concepts(of concept1) "qualified_by" ListCommonName1

considering ListCommonName1 is the closest as in the picture.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT : I think my question is not clear, I will try to do my best to explain it clearly :
Considering a Concept1 with some generics informations, his childs SubConcept1, SubConcept2, ... can get the same generic informations (representing by an objectproperty) ?

EDIT2: Ok, I think I'm beginning to understand what you said about subClassOf and the difference between classes and individuals.
So, if I understand correctly, I can never use rdfs:subClassOf in SWRL rules or in Property Chain because it's concerning only classes's schema and not individuals. So if I use it on individuals it can't work. Right ?

So if it's true, do you know a solution to say that :
If a qualified_by relation exists on a parent concept (concept1  as individual), can it be applied to an individual that is a subConcept (subConcept1 as individual) ?

Sorry i really try to understand where is my understanding problem about owl reasoning, and this problem makes me crazy since a long time ago.

Comment: You have to distinguish between classes and individuals. `rdfs:subClassOf` connects two classes while using an object property expresses the relation of two individuals. If you say `:concept :qualified_by :ListCommonName1` both `concepts` and `:ListCommonName1` are individuals. Having `:subconcept rdfs:subClassOf :concept` makes `:subconcept` and `:concept` being classes. With OWL 2 using the same IRI for a class and individual is possible – so called *punning* – but inference doesn't take into account this.

Comment: Yeah i understand so i have to specify here :Concept is an individual (sorry but you have to read :Concept1 rdf:type :Concept). So can i obtain result in picture ?

Comment: Do you mean i have to use another objectproperty ? with transitive caracteristic ?

Comment: No, that does not work: You have an axiom `:Concept :qualified_by :ListCommonName1` which says something about the **individual** `:Concept`. On the other hand with `:Concept1 rdf:type :Concept` you say that `:Concept1` belongs to the **class** `:Concept`.

Comment: ok i reformulated my post to clarify :concept and :concept1. Did i miss something else ?

Comment: I still don't get it. Now you have two individuals `:Concept1` and `SubConcept1`? How do you express the subclass relationship if those are individuals? Please clean up your question, define classes, properties and individuals and then say what you want to be inferred. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answer.

So I will try to explain my use case.
I have got :

1. some concepts (Tag), some sub-concepts (tag_qualification, tag_concept, tag_object, etc ...). In this particular case, individuals of theses classes are uniques (is it possible to express this constraint in OWL ?).
2. some relationships to express the vocabulary of my ontology.
   Qualified_by is used to represent a tag "qualified_by" another_tag.
3. Considering my individual (rdf:type tag) 'indoor_temperature' :

> subclassof tag<-concept<-thermal<-temperature<-indoor_temperature, etc ...

so indoor_temperature can be "qualified_by" Cold, Hot, etc ... but temperature too (superconcept of indoor_temperature) then outdoor_temperature too (at the same level of indoor_temperature).

Do you know what i mean ? Is my drawing clearer ?
If you look at it one more time, i want to infer orange relationship expressed in the last sentence.
Is there any possibility to infer "qualified_by" relationship over subclasses taxonomy when qualified_by is not directly connected to a tag ?
I really think it's possible.

Moreover i really like your question :

> How do you express the subclass relationship if those are individuals ?

Do you mean it's not possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, a little up !